# Pandas: Checking for discontinuity in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data

```
index      date        hour   value
  0      2020-01-01     0       0
  1      2020-01-01     1       0
  2      2020-01-01     2       0
  3      2020-01-01     3       1
  4      2020-01-01     4       0
  5      2020-01-01     5       0
  6      2020-01-01     6       0
  7      2020-01-01     7       1
 ..          ...        ..     ..
 742     2020-01-31    21       1
 743     2020-01-31    22       1
 744     2020-01-31    23       1
```

In the above data, I want to see if for a given 24-hour window, if `value` is 1 and the previous 3 hours and next 3 hours are not 1, then replace that with 0. E.g. in the above value for `index` 3 will be replaced with 0 as the previous 3 values and the next 3 values are 0.
I can use `np.where` but not sure how to check for the previous 3 rows value and next 3 rows.

Comment: 1. Please always post data or dataframes as copy-pasteable code. 2. Please provide minimal input and required corresponding output. 3. Did you consider [`rolling`?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)?

Comment: Thanks @Gulzar I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `.apply()` which is slow. Can use `.sum()` and compare to center.

```
before = after = 3
mask = df["value"].rolling(window=(before+after) + 1, center=True).sum()==df["value"]

df.loc[mask, "value"] = 0
```

Comment: Nice! I am familiar with ``rolling``  but wasn't aware it could be used for the next n rows as well. If I am not wrong with ``center=True`` that's been made possible, right?